# Avoid maven phase repeatly running in GitLab CI

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

If we define such stages in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
build:
  stage: build
  script: mvn -B compile

test:
  stage: test
  script: mvn -B test

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: mvn -B deploy
```

this works good, but there is one problem that in each job we are running against phases, the preceding pahse will be run. In above example, the test phase will run in both "test" and "deploy" stages. I think it's useless and will add extra pipeline running time. I know I can invoke plugin goal directly, but that will be hard to maintain the pom. Any good idea?

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically you could do this if you split your maven project into multiple modules that did different things.  You could then use the advanced reactor options to resume the build and process the next module using:

```
maven -rf <module name> <command>
```

Note that I do say theoretically.  In practise splitting the build and test phase is largely pointless and very hard to do (unless the test phase is actually an integration-test phase).  It's also a lot of effort for very little gain.

See here for more information on advanced reactor options:

https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

Comment: to clear confusing `-rf` is the short of `--resume-from` ;-)

Comment: The issue here is related to the fact that each GitLab job is totally independent, so `test` job will not have access to `target` Maven folder created while running `build` job.

Comment: That's actually a different issue to running a phase independently.  You can work around this by storing your target directory as an artifact:  ```artifacts:
     paths:
       - target/```